# Why is my integrated screen stuck at 60.05Hz after upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 23.04?

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, intel-graphics, 23.04

Currently got a new Dell Inspiron 15 3511 equipped with Core i5-1135G7 and Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2). Ubuntu 20.04 was preinstalled and I was using the laptop at 1920x1080@120Hz. Later installed Ubuntu 23.04 and, now, I can only go up to 60Hz. Additionally, after upgrading the system, I connected laptop to my 34 inches screen that normally works at 2560x1080@75Hz but all the resolution options were 16:9 with the maximum of 1920x1080@60Hz casuing visuals to strech to fill the screen. Since I did not try connecting it to an external monitor before upgrading, I do not know the behavior of 20.04. My Ubuntu 23.04 works with XWAYLAND right now but changing to Xorg did not help either. Below is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Do not mind the second monitor, it is not the aforementioned 34", but another one that is 24" with max resolution of 1920x1080@60Hz, so it works fine.